# Laravel: Selecting Items with WHERE condition is in joined table

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have two tables (films and reviews). One Film HasMany Reviews and one Review BelongsTo one Film

Relations:
Film.php

```
public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review');
}
```

and Review.php

```
public function film()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Film');
}
```

Since I am using Laravel Eloquent relations, I want to build a list of films ordered by reviews using Eloquent. Reviews go from 0 = non rated, to 5 = maximum rating.

In plain English I need:

- join the two tables
- get all the films that has reviews
- group by film_id
- calculate the average (one film could have many reviews so I need the average)
- organize the resulting list
- get the list

My solutions using the **Query Builder** get an error:

```
$best_films = DB::table('films')
             ->join('reviews', 'reviews.film_id', '=', 'films.id')
             ->select('films.id', 'avg(reviews.rating)')
             ->groupBy('films.id')
             ->orderByRaw('avg(reviews.rating) DESC')
             ->get();
```

With this I get the following error: 
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'avg(reviews.rating)' ...**

Using **Eloquent ORM** I can not order by columns in oteher table. Something like this does not work:

```
 $films = Film::whereHas('reviews')->orderBy('reviews.film_id', 'desc')->get();
```

I get the error:
**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reviews.film_id' in 'order clause'...**

My Question:
Any idea how to solve that problem? (I would prefer using Eloquent Orm)

Comment: I think you need to use `->with('reviews')` on Eloquent `Film::whereHas('reviews')->with('reviews')->orderBy('reviews.film_id', 'desc')->get();`

Comment: Using the "->with('reviews')"  gets the same error: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'reviews.film_id'. Because the WHERE column is in the Joined table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this

```
best_films = DB::table('films')
             ->join('reviews', 'reviews.film_id', '=', 'films.id')
             ->select('films.id', DB::raw('avg(reviews.rating)'))
             ->groupBy('films.id')
             ->orderByRaw('avg(reviews.rating) DESC')
             ->get();
```

Comment: Hier is the solution!. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to short data in your relational model like this

`public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Review')->orderBy('film_id', 'desc');
}`

Comment: This gets back all the films without taking into account or reviews have or not